# undefined reference to `pthread_xxx' when using cmake with googletest

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I follow the step on [incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project) and I can compile and link my test correctly.

But if I install gtest by myself and then I use the installed gtest, I failed the link my test code. I need to add `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")` into my `CMakeLists.txt` and it will work correctly.

So why do I need add the params `-pthread` if I use the installed gtest lib but I don't need to if I follow the step of [incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project)?

Anybody can help me?

## Here is my test code.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(Test C CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread") # without -pthread, it will failed to link pthread_xxxx
include_directories("/usr/local/include")
link_directories("/usr/local/lib")
find_library(GTEST_LIB NAMES gtest)
add_executable(test gtest_demo.cpp)
message(status "gtest: ${GTEST_LIB}")
target_link_libraries(test ${GTEST_LIB})
```

gtest_demo.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
int add(int a, int b) {
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}

TEST(AddCase, AddOK) {
    EXPECT_EQ(3, add(1,2));
}

using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv); 
    RUN_ALL_TESTS(); 
    return 0;
}
```

## Here is how I install gtest

```
mkdir googletest/build \
    && cd googletest/build && cmake .. && make -j10 \
    && cp lib/* /usr/local/lib/ \
    && cp -r googletest/googlemock/include/gmock/ /usr/local/include \
    && cp -r googletest/googletest/include/gtest/ /usr/local/include \
```

## this is the error message

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable test
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::~ThreadLocal()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEED5Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::~ThreadLocal()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED2Ev[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEED5Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::GetOrCreateValue() const':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x79): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::CreateKey()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE9CreateKeyEv[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE9CreateKeyEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<std::vector<testing::internal::TraceInfo, std::allocator<testing::internal::TraceInfo> > >::CreateKey()':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE9CreateKeyEv[_ZN7testing8internal11ThreadLocalISt6vectorINS0_9TraceInfoESaIS3_EEE9CreateKeyEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/local/lib/libgtest.a(gtest-all.cc.o): In function `testing::internal::ThreadLocal<testing::TestPartResultReporterInterface*>::GetOrCreateValue() const':
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0x79): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:85: test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Could you compile with `VERBOSE=1 make` to check the actual command line your compiler is invoked with?

Comment: And please, provide **exact error message**, with filenames and other details.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added it. Please check it. Thank you.

Comment: @YSC I use `VERBOSE=1 make`. The actual command line is `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/test.dir/gtest_demo.cpp.o  -o test   -L/usr/local/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a`. No `lpthread` is added.

Comment: @YSC And I test way of the [incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project). It is `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/test.dir/gtest_demo.cpp.o  -o test   -L/usr/local/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib lib/libgtest_main.a lib/libgtest.a -lpthread`. `-lpthrad` is added. Do you know how it is added?

Comment: You link with plain **static** `gtest`, so this library doesn't contain references to other libraries (e.g. `pthread`) it depends. Other ways for using `gtest` properly handle dependencies of `gtest`.